# Error when trying to use Internal function

Tags: r

I was trying to optimize code and wanted to use the `.Internal` implementation of `vapply` and got an Error I don't understand. (For now I'll take the warning of `?.Internal` seriously, that "Only true R wizards should even consider using this function" and use the user visible `vapply` but I'd like to understand the error better nontheless.)

```
test <- rnorm(10000)
test_l <- as.list(test)

test_2 <- .Internal(vapply(test_l, \(x) x^2, numeric(1), FALSE))
# Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
```

Compare this to the code of the user visible `vapply`:

```
function (X, FUN, FUN.VALUE, ..., USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
{
  FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
  if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
    X <- as.list(X)
  .Internal(vapply(X, FUN, FUN.VALUE, USE.NAMES))
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this does not work?

Some of my hypotheses:

Does it run in another namespace than the function body of the user visible `vapply` or do I call the user visible function instead of the `.Internal` for some other reason?

Is it because the internal `vapply` is a special internal, that works differently than other internals?

The R-ints manual [1] states:

> 2.2 Special internals
>
> There are also special .Internal functions: NextMethod, Recall, withVisible, cbind, rbind (to allow for the deparse.level argument), eapply, lapply and vapply.

But does not give more detail.

Can someone give me more detail on those "Special internals"?

[1] https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive

Comment: I don't know, but since I recently learned how to find C source code for .Internal functions, here is the link https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/24759e282cf210bedfcc34718837c89f1bcb350e/src/main/apply.c#L92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/24759e282cf210bedfcc34718837c89f1bcb350e/src/main/apply.c#L164) refers to `R_DotsSymbol`, i.e., the ellipses. The calling scope does not have the ellipses. It can't because it is not a function call.

You can reproduce the error using standard R code like this:

```
foo <- function() {
  return(...)
}
foo()
#Error in foo() : '...' used in an incorrect context
```

Or with the `.Internal` call to `vapply` like this:

```
bar <- function(X, FUN, FUN.VALUE, USE.NAMES) {
  .Internal(vapply(X, FUN, FUN.VALUE, USE.NAMES))
}

bar(test_l, \(x) x^2, numeric(1), FALSE)
#Error in bar(test_l, function(x) x^2, numeric(1), FALSE) : 
#  '...' used in an incorrect context
```

This works because `...` exists in the calling scope:

```
baz <- function(X, FUN, FUN.VALUE, USE.NAMES, ...) {
  .Internal(vapply(X, FUN, FUN.VALUE, USE.NAMES))
}

x <- baz(test_l, \(x) x^2, numeric(1), FALSE)
```

You won't be able to produce significant faster code by skipping those first few lines of `vapply`. They are not your bottleneck. It might help implementing the function that is repeatedly called by `vapply` with Rcpp but a true performance boost can only be achieved by implementing the whole loop with Rcpp. Calls to R closures are expensive and you want to avoid them in loops with many iterations.

Comment: Completely agree. The overhead of calling `vapply` from inside a closure is tiny though (I get about 5 microseconds in the benchmark). One would need to be calling the R function thousands of times for this to make any difference.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick and useful answer. With regard to optimizing, I agree that other optimizations will give greater speedups more easily - in the end what saved me seconds is that I evaluate the whole thing less often.

Answer (score 1):

Roland's analysis is correct here. There is a hack that allows you to get an ellipsis in the global environment, but it requires the function you pass to `vapply` to take an extra unused argument:

```r
`...` <- (function(...) get("..."))(y = 2)
```

So now you could do:

```r
test <- rnorm(10)
test_l <- as.list(test)

.Internal(vapply(test_l, \(x, y) x^2, numeric(1), FALSE))
#>  [1] 1.49370808 0.02969854 4.80764382 2.96895104 0.69506047 1.53488883
#>  [7] 0.12566700 1.27180579 0.08399010 0.02366073
```

However, this is *not* recommended. Although there is a very small overhead to calling the `.Internal` from inside a closure, as Roland says, this is not going to be the rate-limiting factor in your code.

If we measure it:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  hack = {`...` <- (function(...) get("..."))(y = 2);
   .Internal(vapply(test_l, \(x, y) x^2, numeric(1), FALSE))},
  standard = vapply(test_l, \(x) x^2, numeric(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE))

#> Unit: microseconds
#>      expr min  lq   mean median  uq   max neval cld
#>      hack 9.0 9.3  9.690    9.6 9.8  17.8   100   a
#>  standard 6.7 7.0 15.261    7.1 7.2 817.9   100   a
```

We can see that although the hack is slightly faster on average (and only due to the occasional outlier in the standard version), it is in the order of 5 microseconds per call, so you might save yourself 5 milliseconds if you call this routine 1000 times. When you consider the opacity and difficulty of debugging such an approach, it is simply not worth it.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes that hack is definitely not something I would try. Also I hope no one would accept it in a pull request. But hacks like this always help understand the internals of the language better, thank you :)

Comment: Umm, the hack is not faster, it is slower (because of the repeated calls to the anonymous closure). It looks like you had an outlier in your benchmark. Ignore the mean value and focus on the quantiles.

Comment: @Roland I have re-run the benchmark several times and it always seems to throw up at least one outlier when running the standard `vapply`. The total time it takes to run the standard `vapply` 100 times on my machine is _always_ longer than the the total time it takes to run the hack 100 times, so I don't think I'd be justified in ignoring outliers. In any case, the point is that one shouldn't use the hack - it's there to illustrate that you _could_ get `.Internal` to run `vapply` in the Global Environment, but that there is no reason to do so.

Comment: Might be the JIT compiler. I didn't see an outlier on my system.